# SQL Server query distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, distinct

I'm trying to do a query in SQL Server 2008. This is the structure of my table

```
Recno     ClientNo      ServiceNo
---------------------------------
1234      17            27
2345      19            34
3456      20            33
4567      17            34
```

I'm trying to select `RecNo` however, filtering by distinct `ClientNo`, so for some clients such as client no 17 - they have more than 1 entry, I'm trying to count that client only once. So basically, looking at this table, I'm only supposed to see 3 RecNo's, since there are only 3 distinct clients. Please help

```
Select RecNo, Count(ClientNo)
from TblA
where Count(clientNo)<2
```

Something like this?

EDIT:

The value of `RecNo` is not relevant, I only need to have an accurate number of records. In this case, I'd like to have 3 records.

Comment: Do you actually need the `Recno`'s values?, or just the count?

Comment: To echo what @Lamak said, do you care which `Recno` you get for any given client number? If not, you could do a `group by` combined with a `min` or `max` on `Recno`

Comment: @Lamak - yes, i don't want COUNT of them though.

Comment: Then, in your sample data, what would be the desired result?, which Recno should you choose?.

Comment: @mituw16 - i want to see all the RecNo's only, nothing else. For distinct client

Comment: @Bobski What do you mean you want to see all `Recno`s ? There are 4 unique `Recno`'s in your table, yet in your question you say you only want to see 3 `Recno`'s ????

Comment: @Lamak see edit. Thanks!

Comment: @Bobski In your edit..what is the condition for you to remove `3456` ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, see edit again @mituw16

Comment: i think all you want is `select distinct recno`...

Comment: @Bobski ok, why choose `1234`  instead of `4567`?

Comment: @scsimon no, that doesn't fit

Comment: Are you trying to choose the first instance of `Recno` for a given clientno? In that situation you could do a `rownumber()` type query

Comment: @mituw16 - sorry - i didn't think this through, can i just see something like 1,2,3,4 instead of the recNo's, since for Client 17 I can't really hcoose which one to see which one to not see

Comment: @mituw16 I guess it doesn't really matter, I'm not using the RecNo value for anything, i just want to have an accurate record count - so I guess either way it will work

Comment: Then please edit your question to explain what it is that you actually want

Comment: @Lamak - my apologies - edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oaky you are getting some crazy answers probably becuase your desired result is not clear so I suggest if some of these are not what you need that you clarify your desired result.

If you want the answer 3, I can only assume you want a count of DISTINCT ClientNo's if so it is simply aggregation.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ClientNo) as ClientNoDistinctCount
FROM
    TblA
GROUP BY
    ClientNo
```

Comment: But that's not what op wants. Op wants to count the number of recno values where you can have different clients, that's not the same as counting distinct clientNo

Comment: @Lamak  I am understand your statement but I am not sure the OP is stating what they actually want clearly if you read the sentence " I'm only supposed to see 3 RecNo's, since there are only 3 distinct clients" it seems like he is just looking for distinct clients so I am offering this as an answer in case the OP is just wording things wrong

Comment: But the question says that: `I'm trying to select RecNo however, filtering by distinct ClientNo`

Comment: @Lamak - i edited the question. Matt is correct and his solution gives me the correct answer. Yours is more accurate as it gives me the actual value. I only need to see the number of records, his query returns the correct number of records, and the values are just 1's. In my application I do a recordset.recordcont - and this returns the right number. Thank you both!

Comment: Alright, I get it. But to be sure, if you had another row with values `(5678,19,35)`, what do you want as a result?

Comment: @lamak In this case - I'd still only want to see 3 records - because there are 2 clients with clientNO = 19. I'm only looking to see the number of records for distinct clientNo's.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this will give you the count that you want:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientNo ORDER BY Recno)
    FROM TblA
)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Recno) N
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
   ;with cte1
  As(SELECT Recno,clientno 
  ,row_number() over(partition by clientno order by Recno )RNO FROM TblA)
   Select Recno,clientno 
   From cre1 where RNO=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Choose only `ClientNo` having the max `Recno` (or replace `<` with `>` to choose the min one).

```
Select *
from TblA t1
where not exists(select 1 
         from TblA t2
         where t1.ClientNo = t2.ClientNo and t1.Recno < t2.Recno )
```

BTW, the other solution already mentioned, utilizing `row_number()` needs no CTE in this case

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES *
FROM TblA
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientNo ORDER BY Recno)
```